# Prove that if $X$ is contractible, then the suspension $SX$ is also contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

> If X is contractible, then the suspension SX is also contractible.

I want to prove this by showing the identity on $SX$ is nullhomotopic. Below is my attempt. I was able to construct a homotopy $SX\times I\to SX$ that starts at the identity on $SX$, but it appears to not end up at a constant map.

---

*Proof*. Let $X$ be contractible and consider $SX:=(X\times I)/\sim$ with quotient map $q\colon X\times I\to SX$. Since $X$ is contractible, there is a homotopy $H\colon X\times I\to X$ such that $H(x,0)=x$ and $H(x,1)=x_0$ for every $x\in X$ with $x_0\in X$ fixed. Define $F\colon (X\times I)\times I\to X\times I$ by $F(x,s,t):=(H(x,t),s)$. We have a diagram (I can't seem to draw diagrams, if someone could edit and produce the linked diagram here that would be great!)

https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNCxbMCwwLCIoWFxcdGltZXMgSSlcXHRpbWVzIEkiXSxbMCwxLCJTWFxcdGltZXMgSSJdLFsxLDEsIlNYIl0sWzEsMCwiWFxcdGltZXMgSSJdLFswLDEsInFcXHRpbWVzXFx0ZXh0e0lkfV9JIiwyXSxbMywyLCJxIl0sWzEsMiwiXFx3aWRldGlsZGV7cVxcY2lyYyBGfSIsMix7InN0eWxlIjp7ImJvZHkiOnsibmFtZSI6ImRhc2hlZCJ9fX1dLFswLDMsIkYiXV0=

where the map $\widetilde{q\circ F}$ making the diagram commute exists if $q\times\text{Id}_I$ is a quotient map and $q\circ F$ is continuous that is constant on the fibers of $q\times\text{Id}_I$. The fact that $q\times\text{Id}_I$ is a quotient map follows from $q$ being a quotient map and $I$ being locally compact, and as both $q$ and $F$ are continuous so is the composition $q\circ F$. Now suppose $(q\times\text{Id}_I)(x,s,t)=(q\times\text{Id}_I)(x',s',t')$. Then $(q(x,s),t)=(q(x',s'),t')$, hence $t=t'$ and $q(x,s)=q(x',s')$ so either $s=s'=0$ or $s=s'=1$. If $t=t'$ and $s=s'=0$ then
$$
    (q\circ F)(x,s,t)=q(F(x,0,t))=q(H(x,t),0)=q(H(x',t'),0)=q(F(x',0,t'))=(q\circ F)(x',s',t').
$$
If $t=t'$ and $s=s'=1$ then
$$
    (q\circ F)(x,s,t)=q(F(x,1,t))=q(H(x,t),1)=q(H(x',t'),1)=q(F(x',1,t'))=(q\circ F)(x',s',t').
$$
Therefore $q\circ F$ is constant on the fibers of $q\times\text{Id}_I$, so the map $\widetilde{q\circ F}$ making the diagram commute exists. In particular, we have
$$
    \widetilde{q\circ F}(q(x,s),0)=(\widetilde{q\circ F})\circ(q\times\text{Id}_I)(x,s,0)=(q\circ F)(x,s,0)=q(F(x,s,0))=q(H(x,0),s)=q(x,s)
$$
and
$$
    \widetilde{q\circ F}(q(x,s),1)=(\widetilde{q\circ F})\circ(q\times\text{Id}_I)(x,s,1)=(q\circ F)(x,s,1)=q(F(x,s,1))=q(H(x,1),s)=q(x_0,s)...
$$

Comment: The product of two contractible is contractible and $q$ is continuous so $q(X \times I)$ is contractible? Furthermore, you can show that $\pi_{n+1} (SX) = \pi_n(X)$ ore the converse, I don't really remember

Comment: That's true stably, but not on the nose.  Maybe you're thinking of the loops $\Omega$ version.

Comment: @JulesBesson Quotient maps don't necessarily preserve being contractible, e.g. the quotient map $q:[0,1]\to S^1$ identifying $0$ and $1$...also I know almost nothing about higher homotopy groups.

Comment: right right my bad thanks for correcting me

Comment: @Randall I am confused. Are you saying this statement is not true?

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds  no I am saying that $S$ shifting the homotopy groups that way is generally not so.

Comment: No the statement is true but what I have written is not this is only because you can write a nice contraction that works fine with this particular quotienting...

Comment: But $S$ is shifting homotopy groups, it is sometimes called shifting functor

Comment: Your current homotopy is a great start.  Now you just need to concatonate another homotopy to finish the job.  Here's a hint for the second homotopy: at the end of the first homotopy, the image in $X\times I$ is an interval, which is contractible.  @JulesBesson:  I disagree that $S$ simply shifts homtopy groups.  Compare $\pi_2(S^1)=$ with $\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: On Quiver there is a button that says "LaTeX" on the bottom of the screen. Click it for the markup required to display the diagram.

Comment: It depends if you talk about free or reduced suspension I believe

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see how what you're saying can work, but having a hard time actually doing it. Here is some attempt: Let $[x']=q(x,1)$ for any $x\in X$. Consider another homotopy $H'\colon SX\times I\to SX$ defined by $H'(q(x,s),t):=q(x,t)$. Then it ends at $H'(q(x,s),1)=q(x,1)=[x']$ for every $x\in X$, a constant. Now I can concatonate $\widetilde{q\circ F}$ with $H'$ to get a homotopy $SX\times I\to SX$ that does what I want.

Comment: Does $SX$ denote unreduced suspension?

Comment: @PaulFrost Never heard of that. Here $SX$ is gotten from $X\times I$ by identifying points $(x,0)\sim(x',0)$ and $(x,1)\sim(x',1)$.

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds Yes, it is the unreduced suspension. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds:  It seems me that your new homotopy $H'$ doesn't start where the old one ends.  The old one starts at the map $Id_{SX}$ and ends at the map $f:SX\rightarrow SX$ given by $f(q(x,s)) = q(x_0,s)$.  The new one should start there.  I haven't checked it, but I believe something like $H'(q(x,s), t) = q(x_0,s(1-t))$ will do the trick.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Dumb of me! You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to reason about this kind of thing diagramatically. In the below I use the following notation:

- $\Gamma:X\times I\to X$ is a given contraction of $X$ (at time zero) onto the point $p\in X$ (at time $1$)
- $\gamma:I\times I\to I$ is the following map: $$(s,t)\mapsto\begin{cases}(2t,s)&0\le t\le1/2\\(1,2(1-t)s)&1/2\le t\le 1\end{cases}$$
- $\sigma:\partial I\times I\to I$ is the following map: $$(s,t)\mapsto\begin{cases}0&s=0\\1&s=1,\quad0\le t\le1/2\\2(1-t)&s=1,\quad1/2\le t\le1\end{cases}$$

[image: Diagram]

Because the second diagram remains a pushout ($(-)\times I$ is cocontinuous because $I$ is LCH) you can check that a unique $\Phi:SX\times I\to SX$ is induced, which you can further check is a contraction of $SX$ (at time zero) to the point $q(X\times\{0\})$ (at time one).

This diagram works in stages: first, the suspension is collapsed onto a single spine, the image of $\{p\}\times I$ in $SX$, and then this spine is contracted down to its basepoint.

Comment: This appears to be a bit different than what I was wanting - to show the identity map on $SX$ is nullhomotopic - but I like different ways, so I will accept it.

Comment: @Rough_Manifolds To show the identity map on $SX$ is nullhomotopic is exactly the same thing as to exhibit a homotopy $\Phi$ which takes $\mathrm{Id}\simeq\ast$ for some point $\ast$ (which is what I did) - I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0 \in X$ and $H$ a homotopy from the identity of $X$ to the constant map $x_0$.
You can construct a retract of $\Sigma X$ in two steps : first retracting on $I \times \{x_0\}$ then retracting to $x_0$.
The first retraction is simply $H'((x,s),t)=(H(x,t),s)$ and you can check this is well defined on the suspension. $H'((x,s),0))$ is the identity while $H'((x,s),1)) = (x_0,s)$.
Then the second retraction consists of retracting the segment to the point. It is given by :
$H((x,s),t) = (x_0,(1-t)s)$
You have $H((x,s),1) = (x_0,0) $ constant while $H((x,s),0)= (x_0,s)$ which is the retraction on the interval.

Comment: This answer seems like you just summarized what I wrote without all the leg work, then just rewrote the comment by Jason DeVito. The only new thing you could have done was actually write out the second homotopy, which you did not do. Following the comment by Jason DeVito, what is the second homotopy?

Comment: I edited and have added the second homotopy in my answer.